# Loess/lowess error for dataframe -- ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, statsmodels, loess

I am trying to run the lowess/loess smoother but I get an error: `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

Data is all the same length part of the same source dataframe but there are a couple `NaN` values. I am not sure if that is the issue or if there is something else that the line is missing. I have scoured the internet and nothing is helping to get this to work.

```
from statsmodels.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess import lowess
df['value'] = lowess(df.value, station.Date, is_sorted=True, frac=0.05, it=0)
```

Comment: Have you tried masking the NaN values, to see if the error message still occurs?

Comment: I have not, I am not sure how to do that...

Comment: You can surely find out how to do this here on SO or in tutorials. However, if you are unsure that you know that the masking was succesful, you can also create a copy of your df and remove all rows with NaN values with `dropna()`. [This is all well-documented by the pandas crew.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#dropping-axis-labels-with-missing-data-dropna)

Comment: dropna() but I now get a new error: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Comment: No, you can do this inplace but the point here is not to modify your original data for this test, so `dftest = df.dropna(axis=0)`, then use lowess with this test df. Have you checked that your dataframe structure is still intact? Not that you accidentally deleted `df.value`? Anyhow, this is all guesswork without a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I figured it out by changing it to this in with the drop na: station['loess_5'] = pd.DataFrame(lowess(df.value, np.arange(len(df.value)), frac=0.005)[:, 1], index=df.index, columns=['value'])